# Strategy design pattern with various duck type classes

Tags: python, design-patterns

I've recently picked up the *Head First Design Patterns* book in an effort to become a more efficient and better Python programmer. Unfortunately, the code examples in this book are in Java.

I'm not the [first one](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t338550-python-design-patterns.html) that wishes there was a Python version of this book, but I thought that writing the Python code would be a great exercise.

I've tried to implement the Strategy design pattern from Chapter 1 of *Head First Design Patterns* below in Python. Now, I know that Python is not Java in a general sense, but not in the nitty-gritty sense. So, I'm sure there are more Pythonic things that I can do to this code.

Off the top of my head we could probably implement the `Duck` class `set_fly_behavior()` and `set_quack_behavior()` using the Python `property` built-in.

Any other suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

################################################################################
# Abstract Duck class and concrete Duck type classes.
################################################################################
class Duck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set_fly_behavior(self, fb):
        self.fly_behavior = fb

    def set_quack_behavior(self, qb):
        self.quack_behavior = qb

    def perform_fly(self):
        self.fly_behavior.fly()

    def perform_quack(self):
        self.quack_behavior.quack()

    def swim(self):
        print "All ducks float, even decoys!"

class MallardDuck(Duck):
    def __init__(self):
        Duck.__init__(self)
        fly_instance = Fly()
        self.set_fly_behavior(fly_instance)
        quack_instance = Quack()
        self.set_quack_behavior(quack_instance)
        print "I'm a real Mallard Duck"

class ModelDuck(Duck):
    def __init__(self):
        Duck.__init__(self)
        fly_no_way_instance = FlyNoWay()
        self.set_fly_behavior(fly_no_way_instance)
        squeak_instance = SqueakQuack()
        self.set_quack_behavior(squeak_instance)
        print "I'm a Model Duck"

class DecoyDuck(Duck):
    def __init__(self):
        Duck.__init__(self)
        fly_no_way_instance = FlyNoWay()
        self.set_fly_behavior(fly_no_way_instance)
        mute_instance = MuteQuack()
        self.set_quack_behavior(mute_instance)
        print "I'm a Decoy Duck"

################################################################################
# Fly behavior interface and behavior implementation classes.
################################################################################
class FlyBehavior():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Fly(FlyBehavior):
    def fly(self):
        print "I'm flying!!"

class FlyNoWay(FlyBehavior):
    def fly(self):
        print "I can't fly"

class FlyRocketPowered(FlyBehavior):
    def fly(self):
        print "I'm flying with a rocket!"

################################################################################
# Quack behavior interface and behavior implementation classes.
################################################################################
class QuackBehavior():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Quack(QuackBehavior):
    def quack(self):
        print "Quack"

class MuteQuack(QuackBehavior):
    def quack(self):
        print "<< Silence >>"

class SqueakQuack(QuackBehavior):
    def quack(self):
        print "Squeak"

################################################################################
# Test Code.
################################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":

    print '#'*80
    print "Mallard Duck"
    print '#'*80
    mallard = MallardDuck()
    mallard.perform_quack()
    mallard.perform_fly()

    print '#'*80
    print "Model Duck"
    print '#'*80
    model = ModelDuck()
    model.perform_fly()
    fly_rocket_powered_instance = FlyRocketPowered()
    model.set_fly_behavior(fly_rocket_powered_instance)
    model.perform_fly()

    print '#'*80
    print "Decoy Duck"
    print '#'*80
    decoy = DecoyDuck()
    decoy.perform_fly()
    decoy.perform_quack()
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## The devil’s in the `_details`

Your suggestion is good, but you don’t need a property; you can just use a normal attribute. All your setter does is set the variable, so just do that instead. So, this:

```
self.set_fly_behavior(fly_instance)
```

Can become this:

```
self._fly_behaviour = fly_instance
```

Note my use of `self._fly_behaviour`. Since it’s is an implementation detail of the class, the best practice is to prefix the variable name with an underscore. This tells programmers that it’s not designed to be used externally.

### Aside: naming behaviours

The names `perform_quack()` and `perform_fly()` are very un-Pythonic. Why not just `quack()` and `fly()`? The *perform* tells us nothing—except, maybe leaking an implementation detail to the outside (that these delegated). This isn't something a caller needs to care about.

---

## ABCs

Other than that, you could make your base classes Abstract Base Classes:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

...

class QuackBehavior(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def quack(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, Check):
        required = ["quack"]
        rtn = True
        for r in required:
          if not any(r in vars(BaseClass) for BaseClass in Check.__mro__):
            rtn = NotImplemented
        return rtn
```

This allows you to have a more Pythonic interface for your class.

(Also, note the removal of the empty constructor. Python provides an empty constructor anyway, so don’t bother defining one if you do nothing with it. It’s just useless extra code.)

---

## A functional approach

This is a pretty heavyweight solution for Python. If you know that these behaviours are always just one function, I would argue classes aren’t needed.

Instead, recall that Python functions are first-class objects:

```
def quack(self):
    print("Quack")

def mute_quack(self):
    print "<< Silence >>"

some_duck = Duck()
some_duck.quack = mute_quack
```

---

## A hybrid approach

We can make this work with one small modification: by using a property to convert functions into methods, so that they can be called normally.

(I’m assuming you need access to `self` in the method; if not, leave out that argument, and it’ll work as-is, like a static method.)

```
import types

class Duck(object):
    ...

    @property
    def fly(self):
        return self._fly

    @fly.setter
    def fly(self, value):
        self._fly = types.MethodType(value, self)

    @property
    def quack(self):
        return self._quack

    @quack.setter
    def quack(self, value):
        self._quack = types.MethodType(value, self)
```

### One step further...

Hmm...we’re doing the same thing for both properties.  If you want, we can take it a step further.

Let’s generalise it instead:

```
import types

def method_property(name):
    def getter(self):
        return getattr(self, name)
    def setter(self, value):
        setattr(self, name, types.MethodType(value, self))
    return getter, setter

class Duck(object):
    ...
    quack = property(*method_property("_quack"))
    fly = property(*method_property("_fly"))
```

Just assign the function as needed—perhaps in the constructor of subclasses. Obviously, if you need more complicated behaviours, this might not do. But for simple things, I’d say it’s the better solution.

---

## Constructors for subclassing

Since a duck is useless without a quack and fly behaviour, and all subclasses assign them, it makes sense for the constructor to deal with this:

```
class Duck(object):
    def __init__(self, fly, quack):
        self.fly = fly
        self.quack = quack

    ...

class ModelDuck(Duck):
    def __init__(self):
        Duck.__init__(self, fly_no_way, squeak_quack)
        print "I'm a Model Duck"
```

Or, if you were using your original class’s implementation:

```
class Duck(object):
    def __init__(self, fly, quack):
        self._fly_behaviour = fly
        self._quack_behaviour = quack

    ...

class ModelDuck(Duck):
    def __init__(self):
        Duck.__init__(self, FlyNoWay(), SqueakQuack())
        print "I'm a Model Duck"
```

---

## Conclusion

If we wrap all this together, we end up with two implementations:

- [function based](http://ideone.com/nz5gdw), and
- [class based](http://ideone.com/Owgfjj).

These implementations remove repetition, and will make this sort of thing much easier to work with in Python overall.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed reply. I'll be sure to +1 you once I get enough rep. In the meantime you've given me quite a bit of material to look over and apply to my programming. I'm also going to continue working on more design patterns from the Head First book. Please be on the lookout :)

Comment: I'm still groking some of the code here. For the class based implementation, I'm trying to get a handle on the `__subclasshook__`. In our abstract behaviors we define the builtin `__subclasshook__` to be the `classmethod` of the function `subclasshook`, which is defined at the top of the code. So the `classmethod` builtin should return the Class of the function `subclasshook`. But I thought `__subclasshook__` was only suppose to return `True`, `False`, or `NotImplemented`. I'm certainly missing something, since the code works.

Comment: Also, I'm not quite following the logic here in the for loop of the function `subclasshook(requried)` at the top. My problem is with the line `if not any(r in vars(BaseClass) for BaseClass in Check.__mro__):`. The variable `r` is the name of the abstract method that needs to be implemented in each concrete behavior. So here we check the `__mro__` of the concrete class and all of its base classes(?) for the name of the abstract method that must be implemented. Shouldn't we check to see that the method is in __every__ class of the `__mro__`, not just __any__ class?

Comment: @PythonJin In response to your first comment, `subclasshook()` returns a function, so when we call `__subclasshook__ = classmethod(subclasshook(["fly"]))`, Python evaluates the `subclasshook()` call, and gives `classmethod()` the function that returns `True`, `False`, or `NotImplemented` as the first argument. It does not pass `classmethod()` the `subclasshook()` function itself, just the value returned by it (which happens to be another function). It then makes it a class method and assigns it to `__subclasshook__`.

Comment: @PythonJin In response to comment two, think about how Python works when you call a function. It looks for the function you call in that class, and if it doesn't find it, works up the MRO (which is all of the base classes, with duplicates removed in a certain order - as Python support multiple inheritance this isn't trivial) and checks for it until it finds it. If we checked if it was in *all* classes, then it would be impossible to add functionality into a subclass without it being in the base class.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Ok, so it's the `@abstractmethod` decorator in the abstract base class that enforces the need for my subclasses to implement a particular class method (let's say the `fly` method). But if we had not implemented `fly` in the subclass, `__subclasshook__ = classmethod(subclasshook(["fly"]))` would still return `True`, since it would eventually find the method in the ABC? Furthermore, we never explicitly call `__subclasshook__`, is it implicitly called somewhere? Or have we just redefined it so that future use of `issubclass()` returns what we want?

Comment: +1. @PythonJin: You should prefer attributes over properties in python wherever possible. This is because an attribute lookup doesn't have the computational overhead of a function call. Properties should be used when you have to preprocess the data before assigning or retrieving it (i.e. `myClass.metricLength` could be a property that converts an attribute stored in feet to meters before returning it.)

Comment: @PythonJin Yes, `__subclasshook__()` will say that a class that inherits from the abstract class but doesn't implement the abstract method - but that class will remain an abstract class that we can't create instances of. The `__subclasshook__()` is simply a way of allowing us to neatly check if a class implements an interface using `isinstance()` or `issubclass()` (without relying on type-checking which doesn't suit Python, as a duck-typed language).