# Strategy Design Pattern in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns

I'm reading the awesome Head First Design Patterns book. As an exercise I converted first example (or rather a subset of it) to Python. The code I got is rather too simple, i.e. there is no abstract nor interface declarations, it's all just 'classes'. Is that the right way to do it in Python? My code is below, original Java code and problem statement can be found at http://books.google.com/books?id=LjJcCnNf92kC&pg=PA18

```
class QuackBehavior():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def quack(self):
        pass

class Quack(QuackBehavior):
    def quack(self):
        print "Quack!"

class QuackNot(QuackBehavior):
    def quack(self):
        print "..."

class Squeack(QuackBehavior):
    def quack(self):
        print "Squeack!"

class FlyBehavior():
    def fly(self):
        pass

class Fly():
    def fly(self):
        print "I'm flying!"

class FlyNot():
    def fly(self):
        print "Can't fly..."

class Duck():
    def display(self):
        print this.name

    def performQuack(self):
        self.quackBehavior.quack()

    def performFly(self):
        self.flyBehavior.fly()

class MallardDuck(Duck):
    def __init__(self):
        self.quackBehavior = Quack()
        self.flyBehavior = Fly()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mallard = MallardDuck()
    mallard.performQuack()
    mallard.performFly()
    mallard.flyBehavior = FlyNot()
    mallard.performFly()
```

Comment: This looked [very familiar](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20718/the-strategy-design-pattern-for-python-in-a-more-pythonic-way/20719#20719) - you might want to take a look at my answer to that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, you can pass functions as argument.  This simplifies the "Strategy" Design pattern, as you don't need to create classes just for one method or behavior.  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963965/how-is-this-strategy-pattern-written-in-python-the-sample-in-wikipedia) for more info.

```
def quack():
    print "Quack!"

def quack_not():
    print "..."

def squeack():
    print "Squeack!"

def fly():
    print "I'm flying!"

def fly_not():
    print "Can't fly..."


class Duck:
    def display(self):
        print this.name

    def __init__(self, quack_behavior, fly_behavior):
        self.performQuack = quack_behavior
        self.performFly = fly_behavior

class MallardDuck(Duck):
    def __init__(self):
        Duck.__init__(self, quack, fly)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    duck = Duck(quack_not, fly_not)
    duck.performQuack()
    mallard = MallardDuck()
    mallard.performQuack()
    mallard.performFly()
    mallard.performFly = fly_not
    mallard.performFly()
```

Output:

```
...
Quack!
I'm flying!
Can't fly...
```

Comment: I picked this answer because it actually shows what @WinstonEwert's only proposed. However, this code lets you create a generic Duck, which was not possible in original Java example (that class is abstract). I assumed not having \_\_init__ in Duck() would make it kind-of-abstract in Python... Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Yes, here's some more info on that: http://fw-geekycoder.blogspot.com/2011/02/creating-abstract-class-in-python.html
The reason I had the `__init__` was for my own reasons of testing the script.

Answer (score 7):

```
class QuackBehavior():
```

Don't put `()` after classes, either skip it, or put `object` in there

```
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

There's no reason to define a constructor if you aren't going to do anything, so just skip  it

```
    def quack(self):
        pass
```

You should probably at least `raise NotImplementedError()`, so that if anyone tries to call this it'll complain. That'll also make it clear what this class is doing.

You don't really need this class at all. The only reason to provide classes like this in python is documentation purposes. Whether or not you think that's useful enough is up to you.

```
class Quack(QuackBehavior):
    def quack(self):
        print "Quack!"

class QuackNot(QuackBehavior):
    def quack(self):
        print "..."

class Squeack(QuackBehavior):
    def quack(self):
        print "Squeack!"

class FlyBehavior():
    def fly(self):
        pass

class Fly():
```

If you are going to defined FlyBehavior, you should really inherit from it. It just makes it a litle more clear what you are doing.

```
    def fly(self):
        print "I'm flying!"

class FlyNot():
    def fly(self):
        print "Can't fly..."

class Duck():
```

I'd define a constructor taking the quack and fly behavior here.

```
    def display(self):
        print this.name

    def performQuack(self):
        self.quackBehavior.quack()

    def performFly(self):
        self.flyBehavior.fly()

class MallardDuck(Duck):
    def __init__(self):
        self.quackBehavior = Quack()
        self.flyBehavior = Fly()
```

There's not really a reason for this to be a class. I'd make a function that sets up the Duck and returns it.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mallard = MallardDuck()
    mallard.performQuack()
    mallard.performFly()
    mallard.flyBehavior = FlyNot()
    mallard.performFly()
```